# Android Speech recognition behind firewall

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-developer-api

For some reason, I have to use Android Speech recognition behind firewall.It caused connection problems at speech recognition. But i don't want to use the offline mode. Is there a list of domains that are used for Speech recognition?

Comment: go to play store and update Google.. that's it

Comment: play store and speech recognition service use same domains?

Comment: The IPs I found are: 74.125.142.192 and 173.194.74.192, Google Now seems to work on ports 5228 and 14259. (Source: XDA)
I guess Google Now uses the same address and ports as the API.
Hmmm, this thread says something else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192438/android-google-voice-recognition-server 
What you can do is: Run the app on a virtual device, use wireshark and capture the traffic, then analyze the destination IP and port.

Answer (score 0):

Download dictionary for offline speech recolonization [Tutorial](http://ccm.net/faq/40940-android-download-new-languages-for-offline-speech-recognition)

And your [Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox&hl=en) Update to latest version. some problem in previous Google app so this must be updated

Comment: um..It's not Google app problem.I used android speech recognition API in my app.And my device can only connect to a wifi router which behind firewall.It caused connection problems at speech recognition. So how to  create firewall rules, that's exactly what I want to know.